# Get IDispatch from NPObject

Tags: google-chrome, plugins, com, npapi

Is there a way to get IDispatch interface from NPObject in Google Chrome NPAPI browser extension?

Comment: The answer specified is the correct one for your question, but you may want to consider rephrasing your question to specify what you are actually trying to do.  For example, if you want to create a COM object that wraps a NPObject, that can be done (and is done in FireBreath, http://firebreath.org). Without knowing what you are actually trying to do, all we can tell you is "no, there is no IDispatch interface for an NPObject"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK - no, since the two are unrelated. However you can make use of:

1. [NPP_Invoke](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/NPN_Invoke)
2. [NPP_InvokeDefault](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/NPN_InvokeDefault)
3. [NPP_HasProperty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/NPN_HasProperty)
4. [NPP_HasMethod](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/NPN_HasMethod)

Which are loosely analogous to IDispatch's GetTypeInfo, GetTypeInfoCount and Invoke.

Comment: Yes, there is no `IDispatch` in the NPAPI. It's COM/ActiveX/IE specific.

Comment: Thanks for the edit George, I'm still getting the hang of the formatting :(